# Verification status Google API Developer

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-api, privacy

I made a game that I would like to publish on the paid PlayStore.

1. I was wondering how I can protect the characters I created from
   being used by other people in their games.
2. The word "Verification status" appears on Google API Developer,
       should I fill in the fields that I am leaving empty (See photo)? If yes, can you explain in detail what and how to do it?

Could I publish the game anyway?
I thank you in advance for your availability.

[image: google_api_developer]

Comment: Sounds like the verification is about the app logo mainly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Google's Play Store support staff.

Answer (score 0):

1. To my knowledge there is no reliable approach that would protect your game resources - that being graphical assets or your source code. You can probably make it a little bit harder to read by some obfuscation mechanism or some sort of encoding that will require a special key, but overall it's not worth the time. Just take a look at big titles being cracked and pirated in spite of the fact that the companies that are producing them have millions of dollars to their disposal.
   Besides remember that all resources you create belong to you. You're the owner and creator and it is yours intellectual property. Using them without your consent would equal breaking the law and you could always seek for compensation on the legal route.
2. It all depends if you're using those oAuth etc features in your game

Comment: is there anything that can attest that I'm the author of the characters?

Comment: I don't know what your working pattern was or is, but normally you'd have a local or remote stages of creation of those assets. You could use versioning systems such as `git` were you could `push` all your consecutive changes to. By doing so you'd have all the stages, but you'd publish only the final one.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand.

Comment: Have you made a copy of your resources while working on them on a regular basis? If you have done so, you can always prove it belongs to you, as you'd have all the creation process at your hand and the other person would only have it's final product

Comment: I wouldn't be so preoccupied with your graphical assets being copied. That's breaking a law and you could always seek for compensation. For more information just look up terms such as _copyright infringement_ and _intellectual property_ on the web

Comment: "Also remember that all the resources you create belong to you. You are the owner and the creator and it is your intellectual property. Using them without your consent would amount to breaking the law and you could always seek compensation on the legal path." Is there a document that will attest to it?

Comment: Read this document from [Google Academy](https://playacademy.exceedlms.com/student/activity/14930-introduction-to-intellectual-property)

Comment: Sorry, for the inconvenience, if I understand, I should upload the graphic assets to: https: //eco.copyright.gov/eService_enu/start.swe? SWECmd = Start & SWEHo = eco.copyright.gov & _ga = 2.60789421.1858028880.1583579416-21863455.1583579416

Comment: There are plenty of information out there, just look for the phrases I've pointed out in my previous comment. As for registration you can read at _Fact 3_ from [this link](http://blog.kunvay.com/5-important-facts-you-need-to-know-about-graphic-design-copyright-and-intellectual-property-that-design-school-didnt-teach-you/) - _Registration is not Required to Enforce Your Rights_